# Spring Boot handling region specific configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know that you can have configuration profiles for dev, stage, prod, etc. I'm wondering how to handle configurations for different regions. In prod we might have 3 different regions, while in stage 2, and dev only 1. Some configuration properties might only have 1 value per environment. But some properties will have different values depending on the region. What is the best way to handle this? I don't particularly want to have an application.properties file per environment/region permutation.

Comment: Are you using AWS?  Some things can be autoconfigured in spring cloud based on regions for apps. Another thought is switching to yaml files as you can have multiple configs for different profiles in one file.

Comment: You know that you may have mulitple profiles activated at once right? You can have set of profiles for common settings as well as additional "regional" profiles

Comment: @Antoniossss I didn't know that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can enable multiple profiles and have everything configured that way. You can also express more advanced criterion using profile expressions, there is a section with that exact use case [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-java).

As of Spring Boot 2.1 you can define an expression on the active profiles so you could have something like [this example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml).